# How to connect sql server with the by using server name 127.0.0.1:1433

Tags: sql

I created a database on the server, it return me the server name 127.0.0.1:1433. I need to know how can I connect to it. I used the server name with sql server authentication but it failed. Any suggestion?

Comment: that's the "localhost" address, used by all TCP/IP-enabled devices, to talk to themselves. You can NOT use that address for a "remote" service access, because by definition 127.0.0.1 is always a LOCAL address, referring to the device you're on.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/, help yourself:)

Comment: That IP address is for localhost. How did you get it from the server?

Comment: I don't know. I created a database and it shows the default server for MS SQL 127.0.0.1. I know this is a local ip address, then how can I connect to remote server?